# Lagging scroll with chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, google-chrome

I have a div with overflow auto which scrolls perfectly in FF and Safari but lags in chrome.
It's very slow, almost staked, and i don't really understand why.
The problem appears when i load some gallery (by ajax). I tried to stop some script to see if that is the problem with no results.
Can anyone please help me?
This is the website http://www.dinofattorini.it and you'll see the problem clicking on PORTFOLIO and then GALLERY 1#.

Comment: Works fine in Chrome 21 on a relatively powerful machine (new Macbook Air). Have you got any extensions in your Chrome that could be causing problems? Have you tried it on any other copies of Chrome?

Comment: Try in Google Chrome Canary if work, it is same with Google Chrome 21

Comment: In Google Chrome Canary works fine

Comment: Hi, it's very slow in all browsers (a bit slower in Chrome), because browsers must obtain all photos instead of their thumbnails. You can have a look at some [thumbnail generator](http://quickthumbnail.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems with this. I believe that part of the problem is your use of AJAX for the images. If you could minimize your AJAX, and instead have the images load with the html it would probably be a lot faster.

Also, as Stano stated, a thumbnail generator would probably help a lot.

Good Luck,

-Brian